# Why are the rows not being printed?

Tags: python, sqlite

I've been following the Python examples @ http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("tweet.db")

c = conn.cursor()


for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks ORDER BY price'):
        print row

conn.close()
```

But the rows aren't printing unless I have:

```
purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
```

I'm using the same database and I've inserted data before trying to select it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [commit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit) your inserts:

```
conn.commit()
```

Only when you commit your transactions does sqlite write the rows to the database permanently. Quoting from the documentation:

> This method commits the current transaction. If you don’t call this method, anything you did since the last call to `commit()` is not visible from other database connections. If you wonder why you don’t see the data you’ve written to the database, please check you didn’t forget to call this method.

Alternatively, you could set the [connection isolation level](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.isolation_level) to `None` to auto-commit changes.

```
conn.isolation_level = None
```

Comment: It seems to be apparent that I've not coded in a while. Thanks.